# How to apply a function to all columns in R?

Tags: r

I have a data.frame that look like

```
 res
  date        X0  X1  X3     car
   2000-01-01 167 185 187     A
   2000-01-01 167 185 187     A
   2000-01-01 167 185 187     A
   2000-01-01 167 185 187     A
   2001-01-01 169 186 187     N
   2001-01-01 169 186 187     N
   2001-01-01 169 186 187     N
   2001-01-01 169 186 187     N
```

This will compute the mean or any function for X0:

```
res %>%
     group_by(car) %>% 
          summarise(Myres= mean(X0))
```

How can I apply this to all columns except "date"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option with `collapse`

```
library(collapse)    
fmean(res[2:4], GRP(res, ~ car))
#    X0  X1  X3
#A 167 185 187
#N 169 186 187
```

---

Or as @G.Grothendieck mentioned, `collap` can be used

```
collap(res[-1], ~ car, fmean)
```

Or as

```
collap(slt(res, X0:X3), res$car)
```

where `slt` is shortcut for `fselect` and `collap` is a fast and easy to use multi-purpose data aggregation command (as per documentation)

---

If we want to pass `sens.slope` and extract some components, apply the function as a lambda function

```
library(trend)
collap(res[-1], ~ car, FUN =  function(x) sens.slope(x)$estimates)
```

#### data

```
res <- structure(list(date = c("2000-01-01", "2000-01-01", "2000-01-01", 
"2000-01-01", "2001-01-01", "2001-01-01", "2001-01-01", "2001-01-01"
), X0 = c(167L, 167L, 167L, 167L, 169L, 169L, 169L, 169L), X1 = c(185L, 
185L, 185L, 185L, 186L, 186L, 186L, 186L), X3 = c(187L, 187L, 
187L, 187L, 187L, 187L, 187L, 187L), car = c("A", "A", "A", "A", 
"N", "N", "N", "N")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))
```

Comment: or `res %>% { collap(slt(., X0:X3), .$car) }`

Comment: You are really a master of so many packages :) +1!

Comment: thanks. I tried sens.slope$estimates(res1[2:4], GRP(res1, ~ car))
Error in sens.slope$estimates : objet de type 'closure' non indiçable

Comment: @Tpellirn Not sure about the error.  Is it based on the same data you showed here.  I used `packageVersion('collapse')#
[1] ‘1.5.3’` on `R 4.0.4`

Comment: I just replaced fmean by sens.slope$estimates

Comment: this worked  collap(res[-1], ~ model, sens.slope). but i only want  $estimates?

Comment: @Tpellirn Is the `estimates` a function ?  If it is, then use that in `collap` because the functions in the package is customized for group by operations

Comment: @Tpellirn The `sens.slope` is from which package?

Comment: I this one works collap(res[-1], ~ model, sens.slope).  but i only want $estimates

Comment: from package(trend)

Comment: @Tpellirn you can pass anonymous function as `collap(res[-1], ~ car, FUN =  function(x) sens.slope(x)$estimates)`

Comment: @Tpellirn the updatedd code  should work for you

Answer (score 5):

For this, you can do:

```r
res %>%
  group_by(car) %>%
  summarize(across(-c(date), mean)
```

This says "apply the function `mean` to every column except for `date`, grouped by `car`

Answer (score 2):

Maybe if you share a reproducible excerpt of your data we can help you better, but in general you can use `summarise_if` function of `dplyr` package for this purpose:

```
library(lubridate)
res %>% group_by(car) %>% summarise_if(!is.Date, mean)
```

this might help because I got the similar results from the following code on `iris` data:

```
> iris %>% group_by(Species) %>% summarise_if(is.double, mean)
# A tibble: 3 x 5
  Species    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
  <fct>             <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl>
1 setosa             5.01        3.43         1.46       0.246
2 versicolor         5.94        2.77         4.26       1.33 
3 virginica          6.59        2.97         5.55       2.03
```

Comment: In the newer version, you could use `summarise(across(where(is.numeric), mean))`

Comment: You are absolutely right and thank you for the suggestion. I totally forgot about `where` and was figuring out how to apply the predicate function. Thank you very much, It's a pleasure to have you here and learn from you dear @akrun.

Comment: FWIW, `summarize_if` (as well as `summarize_at`, `mutate_at, `mutate_if`, etc.) are deprecated in `dplyr 1.0.0+`